# Почему возникают I/O события после рарзыва соединения в IOCP сервере?

Tags: c++, tcp, сокеты, iocp

Переписываю видео-сервер на IOCP. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при разрыве соединения `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` продолжает выбирать события уже удалённого объекта, что рано или поздно приводит к вылету сервера. Опишу немного логику работы сервера...

Поток обработки соединений выглядит так:

```
unsigned int __stdcall WorkerThread(void * param){
    int ThreadId = (int)param;

    while(WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(EventShutdown, 0)){
        DWORD BytesTransfered = 0;
        OVERLAPPED *asyncinfo = nullptr;
        Client *client = nullptr;
        BOOL QCS = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &BytesTransfered, (PULONG_PTR)&client, &asyncinfo, INFINITE);

        if(!client){
            printf("No client\n");
            break;
        }
        if((QCS == 0) || (QCS != 0 && BytesTransfered == 0) ){
            printf("Removing %u before switch, error %d\n", client->Socket(), WSAGetLastError());
            printf("QCS %d / transferred %lu bytes / OLS %d\n", QCS, BytesTransfered, asyncinfo != nullptr);
            RemoveClient(client);
            continue;
        }

        switch(auto opcode = client->CheckEvent(BytesTransfered)){
            case OPCODE_RECV:{
                // Получили данные...
                cxp_data content; // structure for video server command exchange custom protocol
                switch( opcode = cxp_parse(data,content) ){
                    case A_CAMERA_POST:{
                        if( auto agent = client->GetAgent() ){
                            content.user_id = agent->id;
                            StreamSourceProcessing(content, agent->camera, CXP_CAMERA);
                        }
                        if((SOCKET_ERROR == client->Recv()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                            RemoveClient(client);
                        break;
                    }
                    // Другие блоки...
                    case S_STREAM_QUERY:{
                        data =  /* данные для проверки хеша */;
                        if( content.hash == /* функция хеширования */ ){
                            EnterCriticalSection(&LOCK.agents);
                            for(auto it = Agents.begin(); it!= Agents.end(); ++it){
                                Agent *agent = *it;
                                if( agent->id != content.user_id ) continue;
                                EnterCriticalSection(&LOCK.queries);
                                if( client->GetQuery()) client->SetQuery(opcode ^ CXP_USER_DATA, agent);
                                else if( client->SetQuery(opcode ^ CXP_USER_DATA, agent))
                                    Queries.emplace_back(client->GetQuery());
                                LeaveCriticalSection(&LOCK.queries);
                                break;
                            }
                            LeaveCriticalSection(&LOCK.agents);
                        }
                        if((SOCKET_ERROR == client->Recv()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                            RemoveClient(client);
                        break;
                    }
                    ........
```

В запросе `S_STREAM_QUERY` наблюдающий (браузер, подключенный по WebSocket) публикует намерение получать стрим от определённого агента и уходит в `recv` пока не начнёт получать запрашиваемые пакеты или не отключится сам.

В запросе `A_CAMERA_POST` агент (приложение-стример) присылает видео пакет и вызывает для его обработки функцию `StreamSourceProcessing`, которая выглядит так:

```
void StreamSourceProcessing(cxp_data &data, exchange_info &exin, unsigned char type){
    EnterCriticalSection(&LOCK.agents);
    exin.timestamp = DayTimeMs();
    LeaveCriticalSection(&LOCK.agents);
    // Buffering multicast packet
    std::string packet = cxp_pack(CXP_AGENT | type, data);
    packet = websocket::encode(packet, FIN_BINARY);
    // Writing data to disk if recording
    if( RecordEnabled ){
        EnterCriticalSection(&LOCK.records);
        exin.recorder.Push(data.payload, data.duration);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&LOCK.records);
    }
    // Retransmitting packet to supervisors
    EnterCriticalSection(&LOCK.queries);
    for(auto it = Queries.begin(); it != Queries.end();){
        Query *query = *it;
        if( query->type & type == 0 ){ ++it; continue; }
        if( query->agent->id != data.user_id ){ ++it; continue; }
        Client * supervisor = query->owner;
        supervisor->SetSend(&packet[0],packet.size());
        if((SOCKET_ERROR == supervisor->Send()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError())){
            supervisor->UnsetQuery();
            RemoveClient(supervisor);
            it = Queries.erase(it);
        }
        else ++it;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&LOCK.queries);
}
```

То есть, при получении пакета данных от агента, сервер проходится по запросам супервайзеров и рассылает пакет всем, кто запросил стрим от данного агента. Получается что-то вроде подписки на событие со стороны браузера(ов).

Так вот, когда наблюдающий в веб-интерфейсе прекращает смотреть стрим (закрывает окно, разрывая соединение WebSocket), сервер корректно обрабатывает `fin close`, закрывает сокет, УДАЛЯЕТ объект связанного клиента... а дальше начинается череда непонятных мне событий, которые попадают в блок `if((QCS == 0) || (QCS != 0 && BytesTransfered == 0)`. В результате чего несколько раз вызывается деструктор объекта клиента, попадая однажды на область памяти уже занятую другим процессом, и сервер естественно крашится. В деструкторе прописано следующее:

```
Client::~Client(){
    Disconnect();
    if( query ) delete query;
    if( agent ) delete agent;
    in.data.len = out.data.len = 0;
    in.data.buf = out.data.buf = nullptr;
    delete [] buffer;
}
void Client::Disconnect(){
    if( INVALID_SOCKET!= connection ){
        shutdown(connection, SD_BOTH);
        while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&asyncinfo)) Sleep(0);
        closesocket(connection);
        connection = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
}
```

Отрабатывает деструктор корректно, иначе повис бы на `HasOverlappedIoCompleted`.

На данный момент отладка проходит с одним рабочим потоком, одним агентом и одним наблюдателем. Если перестроить сервер на принцип запрос-ответ, то есть агент пишет данные в блок `Send` супервайзера, который периодически опрашивает сервер на наличие новых блоков, то такой проблемы не наблюдается. Но это лишние запросы, проблемы с синхронизацией при высоких пингах и тд... Схема с "подпиской на события" работала на сервере с thread-per-client архитектурой (которая уже задыхается от количества потоков), а вот с событийной моделью IOCP возникла данная проблема.

Картина в WireShark такая:
[image: WireShark log]

Лог сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как перестать получать эти события после закрытия соединения?**

Может я неправильно закрываю соединение, или что-то ещё... Схема "запрос-ответ" плохо вписывается в задачи сервера - уже пробовал, под нагрузкой стрим сильно тормозит. Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить ситуацию.

Comment: Воообще-то эти куски очень далеки от [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Совершенно непонятно, как это все стартует, что с чем синхронизируется, кто чем владеет, зачем вручную вызывается `delete`, почему в деструкторе происходит io и собственно почему разрушается объект у которого `HasOverlappedIoCompleted` еще может быть не завершено. Как я вам советовал в предыдущем вопросе, сделайте однопоточный обработчик и обязательно устраните ручное управление ресурсами (ну или комментарии пишите для каждой операции).

Comment: @VTT, я же написал, что в отладочных целях делаю обработку в одном потоке, как Вы и рекомендовали. Даже если я использую `shared_ptr` вместо сырых указателей, это не изменит суть вопроса - откуда берутся события на соединении, для которого вызван `shutdown` с флагом `SD_BOTH`?